# Iterate over JSON array and assign it's values to object. JavaScript

Tags: json, for-loop

I have a JSON array like this

`[
{"id": "someId",
 "name": "someName",
 "other": "other"},
{"id": "someId1",
 "name": "someName1",
 "other": "other1"}
]`

And i need to iterate over it to retrieve key:value pairs and assign it to object. I need it because i don't need some of the elements and i want some styling.

So, after this manipulation i want to have:

```
id=someId
name=someName
other=other
id=someId1
name=someName1
other=other1
```

I will have this after JSON.stringify(created object.)

So for now i have

```
var data = {};
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
    data[docs[i]._id] = docs[i]._id;
}
console.log(data);
```

After this i have

```
someId = someId
```

Sorry for mistakes.
The Update !!!!!!!!!!

So the JSON just a sample. The real JSON is returned from mongodb that is why it's valid.

In the for loop i have:
`data[docs[i]._id] = docs[i]._id;`
and return 
`someId = someId`
but i need 
`id = someId`

So i can't assign key in the loop into object because it takes the value instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, `"name: "someName"` is missing a `"`. Is this a real problem or was this error introduced when you wrote your question?

Comment: You can't do that. Each property specified on an object exists exactly one time, and points to a single value. You can't have two `id` properties that have different values, you'd end up with one `id` property that has the last assigned value.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally unsure what you want exactly, but if you want to iterate over your array of json objects, then you can use jQuery's `.each` like this:

```
var arr = [ 
    {'id': 'someId', 'name': 'someName', 'other': 'other'}, 
    {'id': 'someId1', 'name': 'someName1', 'other': 'other1'} 
 ];

$(arr).each(function(index,elem){
     console.log(elem.Id);
     console.log(elem.name);
     console.log(elem.other);

    //or watever you want to do with the values
});
```

moreover: make sure your json objects are valid. In the second json Object, there's a missing double quote from the key `name` of yours.

Comment: I can use only plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

In Plain JavaScript you can write something similar as follows

```
 var arr = [ 
    {'id': 'someId', 'name': 'someName', 'other': 'other'}, 
    {'id': 'someId1', 'name': 'someName1', 'other': 'other1'} 
 ];



 //plain javascript for in loop
 for ( var key in arr){     
  var nodes = arr[key]
  // get to the nested obj
    for(var innernodes in nodes){
    console.log(innernodes + ' : ' + nodes[innernodes]);
  }
}
```